# Ionic 6 / Tab navigation / How to preserve tab navigation position?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, vue-router

I've got an Ionic 6 + VueJS project.

I've managed to configure simple tabs but I'm struggling to achieve the following logic.

When navigation between tabs i'd like to preserve the navigation state for each of the tabs.

For example,

Step 1) On **Tab1** I am navigating into nested components.

Step 2) Then move to **Tab2**

Step 3) Then get back to **Tab1** - and here is the problem. When I get back to Tab1 I am navigated to the initial page/vue for **Tab1** but I'd like to be into the last nested vue I've been on **Tab1** before moving to **Tab2**.

For a visual example I've attached 3 screenshots from GitHub iOS app.
There you can see how the user can navigate

- from Tab1(Home) -> to Starred
- then move to Tab2(Notifications)
- and then get back to Tab1(Home) but the user will remain in Starred (last vue navigated in **Tab1** before leaving the tab).

Is this behaviour achievable with **Ionic 6**?

Thank you so much in advance.

[image: Tab1]
[image: Tab2]
[image: Tab1-2]

Comment: i am looking for this since last 3 months :D

Comment: not sure exactly what you are doing but that functionality is provided out of the box, you shouldn't have to change anything. I suspect you have configured you routing incorrectly

Comment: Yes, it is, but in native applications. Are you sure that this is possible with vue-router or any Ionic related router?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to switch back and get to the home page, not a sub-page. Can you provide your router ?